# Change date format with tibble() in R

Tags: r, date

I have some data that shows the date only in year-month, this makes it difficult to work with in plots etc, because of the character. as.Date does not work in this case. So how can I use tibble to format this into year-month-day?

This is what I have tried

```
tibble(USTB$Dates)
tibble(USTB$Dates, "1934-01")
tibble(USTB$Dates, paste0("1934-01", "-01"))
tibble(ymd(paste0("1934-01", "-01")))
```

I get the change to year-month-day, but it only changes for the first day, meaning every date is now 1934-01-01.

Any ideas?

Comment: Right now it's pretty unclear what you're doing. I'm assuming `ymd` is from `lubridate`, but it's good to include what packages you're working with. Without having any of your data, we can't recreate this, and for a question about formatting that's pretty crucial. You've also just created a column that is nothing more than "1934-01-01"—what were you trying to do there, and what did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me to add day (`-01`) and convert to date (to make it easier to work with in plots):

> USTB$Dates <- as.Date(paste0(USTB$Dates, "-01"))